# Korean in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, fonts, korean

Notepad++ (v6.3) is my go-to text editor, a great program. Chinese (Simplified and Traditional), Japanese, Polish, etc all display fine...but not Korean characters which are displayed as little boxes. When I copy the text to Notepad it displays correctly.

This is an example of the text I am trying to display (from `Notepad`):

[image: Notepad displaying Korean correctly]

And this is how the same text appears in `Notepad++`:

[image: Notepad++ displaying boxes for Korean]

Things I have tried:

- In Notepad, checked the font (`Format > Font...`). This is set to `Courier New`. Also tried `Lucida Console`. Korean characters always display fine.
- In Notepad++, check the font (`Settings > Style Configurator...`, then `Global Styles > Global override` and `Global Styles > Default Style`). This is set to `Courier New`. Also tried `Lucida Console`. Korean characters are displayed as boxes. The vast majority of fonts do not display Korean correctly.
- In Notepad++ as above, a small minority fonts that do display Korean correctly. Examples of working fonts are `Batang`, `Dotum`, `Droid Sans Fallback`, `Estrangelo Edessa` and a few others. I am not sure where these fonts came from, as I do a lot of internationalisation work I think I installed a few Asian language packs.

How do you display Korean characters? The font should be fixed-width and ideally `Courier New`.

#### UPDATE

Interestingly, if I put the Korean on the same line as Chinese, Thai or Japanese, it displays correctly:

```
컨베이어 동작중 same line Chinese last 输送带在运行
输送带在运行 same line, Chinese first 컨베이어 동작중
컨베이어 동작중 same line as some Thai สายพานเดิน
```

But it displays as boxes if the Korean text is on by itself (or with other languages I've tried like English, Polish, Russian, Greek, etc).

Comment: I have a suspicion it would depend on your Windows version. You aren't still using XP, are you?

Comment: did you try [Noto Mono](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) or [Roboto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono)?

Comment: @grawity I suspect this is windows 7, because win XP classic's title bar is higher and the gradient and color is different

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No, those fonts are not installed on my system. I've had a look at the font and it does look good.

Comment: Does it turn into squares if you pretty enter at the end of a line where it displays correctly? What locale do you have set? Rather than guess, could you confirm what OS you're running?

Comment: Are you stuck using 6.3? Can you use 7.3 or later?

Comment: @Seth: Not sure of the relevance of the OS, but it was an older PC running Windows XP. I think its the version of Notepad++ (v6.3) possibly combined with running on XP). v6.6.9 (running on my home laptop running Windows 8.1) does not show the problem.

Comment: @Pythonic: I'll see if I can update my v6.3. Generally NPP works great, it is just this one (pretty minor) bug.